# React - How to properly load data with pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On start, I'm loading the data in useEffect like this:

```
 const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
 const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(12);

 useEffect(() => {
    const loadVehicles = async (dealershipId, id) => {
      try {
        const data = await getUserRequests(dealershipId, id, {
          offset: (page - 1) * perPage,
          limit: perPage,
        });

        setRequests(data.results);
      } catch (err) {}
    };

    const loadUser = async (userId) => {
      try {
        const user = await getUserById(userId);

        setSelectedUser(user);
      } catch (err) {}
    };

    const loadData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      await loadVehicles(dealershipId, userId);
      await loadUser(userId);

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    loadData();
  }, [dealershipId, page, perPage, userId]);
```

Here, in the dependecy array I have "page" and "perPage", which are for pagination for vehicles. When I go to, for example, second page:

```
const changePageHandler = (pageNumber) => {
    setPage(pageNumber);
  };
```

`page` is updating, and then useEffect is calling. But the problem is that I just want to call `loadVehicles()` and not the `loadUser()` function.

And when I put `loadVehicles(dealershipId, userId)` function outside of the useEffect, and then call it after `setPage(pageNumber)`, it's not getting the right page, because `page` is not updated yet.

How can I call only `loadVehicles()` with the correct page?

Answer (score 1):

You should use another "useEffect" hook for handling page changes. Also it is better to define your functions outside your hooks so you can use them in other places as well.

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(12);
const loadVehicles = async (dealershipId, id) => {
      try {
        const data = await getUserRequests(dealershipId, id, {
          offset: (page - 1) * perPage,
          limit: perPage,
        });

        setRequests(data.results);
      } catch (err) {}
};
const loadUser = async (userId) => {
      try {
        const user = await getUserById(userId);

        setSelectedUser(user);
      } catch (err) {}
 };
const loadData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      await loadVehicles(dealershipId, userId);
      await loadUser(userId);
      setIsLoading(false);
};
 useEffect(async() => {
    await loadData();
 }, [dealershipId, userId]);
 useEffect(async() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await loadVehicles(dealershipId, userId);
    setIsLoading(false);
 }, [page, perPage]);
```

I am pretty sure you will understand the concept. The code above is just a hint.

Comment: But in this situation, when you first load the page, loadVehicles() will be called 2 times, because of two useEffect(), right ?

Comment: yeah, you don't need it in the first useEffect.

Comment: But how can I correctly set the loading state now ? Because loadUser() and loadVehicles()  are now separated.